# python return within loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, return

If I define:

```
def hasNoX_2(s):
    if type(s)!=str:
       return False
    for c in s:
        if c!='x' or c!='X':
           return True
    return False
```

and enter `hasNoX_2('Xenon')`, `True` is returned and I'm not sure why. Nothing is being returned in the first If statement, since it only returns `False` if `s` is NOT a string. So what is the for loop "looking" at when it  says, "Hey, I don't see `'x'` or `'X'`, so I can return `True`?"

Comment: because your logic tests if at least one letter is not x. Just run manually through your code and you'll see why.

Comment: it returns on first itteration, because evaluation of your `if` statement is True or False, which is obviously True

Comment: I've fixed the indentation

Comment: the code returns True if ANY character in the string is not an 'x'  or 'X'

Comment: Actually, it will always return True - even for the string 'xxxxx'. the only string it will return False for is the empty string `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus just on the if statement

```
if c!='x' or c!='X':
```

This is a boolean expression with two terms

- `c != 'x'` and
- `c != 'X'`

As you use the `or` operator, if either term evaluates as True, then the entire expression evaluates as True. If the expression evaluates as True, then the body of the `if` statement (in this case `return True`) is executed.

Here is the standard truth table for an `or` expression (A or B)

```
 A or B     | A = False | A = True |
 ----------------------------------
| B = False | False     | True     |
| B = True  | True      | True     |
```

As you can see, the result is `False` **only** if both terms are False

Let's look at how your expression evaluates for each type of input

```
c                   | c != 'x' | c != 'X' | or expression |
----------------------------------------------------------
'x'                 | False    | True     | True          |
'X'                 | True     | False    | True          |
any other character | True     | True     | True          |
```

In short, your expression will always evaluate as True - and the `if` branch will always be taken.

So, the function will `return True` when it examines the first character in the provided string.

The only ways this function can return False are

- If something other than a `str` is provided
- If an empty string is provided - because the `for` loop is never entered.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suppouse you trying to achieve True if all chars in input string not equal 'x' or 'X'.

If so, you could simply use the following code:

```
def hasNoX_2(s):

    if isinstance(s, str):
        return 'x' not in s.lower()

    return False

print(hasNoX_2('Xenon'))
print(hasNoX_2('eenon'))
```

Comment: This is valid if you have interpreted the OP's intent correctly. However, they are actually asking why their code always returns True. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You iterate in your for loop through each character in the string. So it's looking at each character. Pretty much your loop is looking for when those if statement is true.

However using or if one of them is true the whole thing conditional evaluates to true so use and instead to make sure both statements are true

Comment: See my answer - the if statement evaluates as true for ALL characters.

Comment: Right I see now that person would most likely have to use and to get both cases

Comment: Probably .. but the function name is unhelpful. Does the function return True if there are "No X's in the string" or if there is "something other than X in the string"? That's why I just tried to focus on explaining the result they were seeing.